# Can EXISTS make this query more efficient?

Tags: sql, select, exists

I want to retrieve only students who have unacceptable grades. My original query is:

```
SELECT ssm.STUDENT_ID,COUNT(srcg.GRADE_TITLE) AS POSTED_GRADES
    FROM STUDENT_ENROLLMENT ssm, STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES srcg
    WHERE ssm.SYEAR='2010' 
    AND ssm.SCHOOL_ID='12' 
    AND ssm.GRADE_ID IN ('140','141','142','143','144','145')
    AND srcg.STUDENT_ID=ssm.STUDENT_ID 
    AND srcg.SYEAR='2010' 
    AND srcg.SCHOOL_ID='12' 
    AND srcg.MARKING_PERIOD_ID='434' 
    AND srcg.GRADE_TITLE IN ('1','2','F','D')               
    GROUP BY ssm.STUDENT_ID;
```

but I don't care about the count; I only want to find students who have any bad grades. I was trying an alternate query:

```
SELECT ssm.STUDENT_ID
    FROM STUDENT_ENROLLMENT ssm
    WHERE ssm.SYEAR='2010' 
    AND ssm.SCHOOL_ID='12' 
    AND ssm.GRADE_ID IN ('140','141','142','143','144','145')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT srcg.GRADE_TITLE from STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES srcg, STUDENT_ENROLLMENT ssm
    WHERE srcg.STUDENT_ID=ssm.STUDENT_ID 
    AND srcg.SYEAR='2010' 
    AND srcg.SCHOOL_ID='12' 
    AND srcg.MARKING_PERIOD_ID='434' 
    AND srcg.GRADE_TITLE IN ('1','2','F','D'));
```

but it returns more records, so obviously I'm doing something wrong. Is there a way to use EXISTS that will return the same results as the first query but which is more efficient?

Comment: Have you tried it and checked the performance?

Comment: I can't see much wrong. Is it possible that you could have duplicate Student_IDs on Student_Enrollment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience EXISTS is not something you should use if you're interested in efficiency.  Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ssm.STUDENT_ID
FROM STUDENT_ENROLLMENT ssm
INNER JOIN STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES srcg
  ON (srcg.STUDENT_ID = ssm.STUDENT_ID)
WHERE ssm.SYEAR='2010' AND
      ssm.SCHOOL_ID = '12' AND
      ssm.GRADE_ID IN ('140','141','142','143','144','145') AND
      srcg.SYEAR='2010' AND
      srcg.SCHOOL_ID = '12' AND
      srcg.MARKING_PERIOD_ID = '434' AND
      srcg.GRADE_TITLE IN ('1','2','F','D')
```

Make sure you have indexes on the following fields or groups of fields:

- STUDENT_ENROLLMENT(STUDENT_ID)
- STUDENT_ENROLLMENT(SYEAR, SCHOOL_ID, GRADE_ID)
- STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES(STUDENT_ID)
- STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES(SYEAR, SCHOOL_ID, MARKING_PERIOD_ID, GRADE_TITLE)

Also, be sure that the constants you are using match the data types of the columns involved.  All the constants in this statement are given as character strings - are all the fields really character columns, or are they numbers (for example, STUDENT_ENROLLMENT.SYEAR)?  Forcing the database to perform unnecessary conversions can cause it to do some truly horrendous things, such as converting a numeric column value to a string so the converted column value can be compared to a string constant.  This can guarantee a very slow table scan with horrible performance.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You get more records because you aren't eliminating duplicates like in the first query using `GROUP BY`.  Put the `GROUP BY` back in, or add a `DISTINCT` and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the join to `student_enrollment` inside the exists clause.

```
 SELECT ssm.STUDENT_ID, COUNT(*) AS POSTED_GRADES
   FROM STUDENT_ENROLLMENT ssm
  WHERE ssm.SYEAR = '2010' 
    AND ssm.SCHOOL_ID = '12' 
    AND ssm.GRADE_ID IN ('140','141','142','143','144','145')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT srcg.GRADE_TITLE 
                 from STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES srcg
                WHERE srcg.SYEAR = '2010' 
                  AND srcg.SCHOOL_ID = '12' 
                  AND srcg.MARKING_PERIOD_ID = '434' 
                  AND srcg.GRADE_TITLE IN ('1','2','F','D')
              );
GROUP BY ssm.STUDENT_ID
```

If the STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES table is huge, this can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have a long-standing dislike for "distinct", as it has hidden bugs from me in the past. I'd recommend this:

```
select STUDENT_ID from 
(SELECT ssm.STUDENT_ID,COUNT(srcg.GRADE_TITLE) AS POSTED_GRADES
    FROM STUDENT_ENROLLMENT ssm, STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES srcg
    WHERE ssm.SYEAR='2010' 
    AND ssm.SCHOOL_ID='12' 
    AND ssm.GRADE_ID IN ('140','141','142','143','144','145')
    AND srcg.STUDENT_ID=ssm.STUDENT_ID 
    AND srcg.SYEAR='2010' 
    AND srcg.SCHOOL_ID='12' 
    AND srcg.MARKING_PERIOD_ID='434' 
    AND srcg.GRADE_TITLE IN ('1','2','F','D')               
    GROUP BY ssm.STUDENT_ID);
```

Comment: Agreed, I consider `DISTINCT` a code smell as it is often used as a quick fix to remove duplicate results, with terrible performance consequences.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
    SELECT distinct ssm.STUDENT_ID
    FROM STUDENT_ENROLLMENT ssm, STUDENT_REPORT_CARD_GRADES srcg
    WHERE ssm.SYEAR='2010' 
    AND ssm.SCHOOL_ID='12' 
    AND ssm.GRADE_ID IN ('140','141','142','143','144','145')    
    AND srcg.STUDENT_ID=ssm.STUDENT_ID 
    AND srcg.SYEAR= ssm.SYEAR 
    AND srcg.SCHOOL_ID=ssm.SCHOOL_ID
    AND srcg.MARKING_PERIOD_ID='434' 
    AND srcg.GRADE_TITLE IN ('1','2','F','D')
```